# I Want My Auto Moving Car To Get Affected By Gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm doing a game where the car automatically moves so whenever the car hits an object it continues floating in the air going forward without begin affected by gravity so that was my main code, I'm still kinda new to this :\

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

then I tried adding this to my code

```
void Start()
{
    coll = GetComponent<Collider>();
    coll.isTrigger = true;
}

// Disables gravity on all rigidbodies entering this collider.
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.attachedRigidbody)
        other.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = true;
}
```

but it's still not affected by this whatever I do it just doesn't work an continuously keeps going forward can you help me fix this problem I'm nearly done on that game so if you could help me I'd be very Thankful <3

Note:The car have RigidBody and is affected by gravity and have a huge mass but this doesn't affect any

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure isKinematic is set to false.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   other.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = true;
   other.attachedRigidbody.isKinematic = false;
}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if(col.collider.CompareTag("taghere") || col.collider.name == "Name")
    {
       // you have to mention the script in which rigidbody you want to disable
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your time, but nah dude I guess I understand where the problem at, its in the                                                                                       
  "void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}"                                                                                                                                  but I still can't fix it this command disables every order givin to the car , as now I can't even turn the car right or left so if you could give me a better one where it make the car free

Comment: You should try using a OnCollisionEnter Instead and use the name of whatever collides with the script. I will edit the above script in my answer

Comment: Thanks I'll Try it and post my final code and what worked and what didn't cuz I been searching alot but still no straight answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a rigidbody to a gameobject you are effectively handing over direct control of the translation to the rigidbody, and you should no longer alter the transform directly.

The easiest way would be to set the velocity of the plane you want to move in only

```
void FixedUpdate(){
      rigidBody.velocity = new Vector3( speed.x, speed.y,rb.velocity.z);
}
```